# How can I web scrape information from a website that has all the tags in the <pre>preformatted tag section?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, tags

I am creating a python crawler that scrapes information from the Interpol website. I was successfully able to scrape information from the first page like names of people, date of birth, nationality etc. In order to scrape information from the second page, I first got the URL from  tag and clicked on the link using my program. When I went to the URL, I found out that all the information(meaning all the tags) were in the < pre > tag section. I am confused about why that is the case. So my question is how can I get information from inside the pre-tag section where all the other tags are. I am trying to get names of people, birthdays, their corresponding links, etc. I am using selenium btw. I will put down the URL of the website. And the URL of the second page that I found in the  tag. I hope that helps you guys understand what I am talking about.

**Main Website:**
https://www.interpol.int/en/How-we-work/Notices/View-Red-Notices

**The second-page link I found in the  tag:**
https://ws-public.interpol.int/notices/v1/red?resultPerPage=20&page=2

The code for the problem I have so far will be posted down below:

`````
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException, NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://www.interpol.int/en/How-we-work/Notices/View-Red-Notices'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="c:\\SeliniumWebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)  //to go the website
url = [] //to get all the URLs of the people
names = [] //to get the names of the peoples
age = [] //to get the age of the people
nationality = [] //to get the nationality of the people
newwindow = [] //to get all the next page links
y = 0
g = 1
   try:
        driver.get(driver.current_url)

        main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'noticesResultsItemList'))
        )

        links = main.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
        years = main.find_elements_by_class_name("age")
        borns = main.find_elements_by_class_name("nationalities")

        for link in links:
            newurl = link.get_attribute('href')
            url.append(newurl)
            names.append(link.text) //adding the names
            y += 1

        for year in years:
            age.append(year.text)  //adding the age to list

        for nation in borns:
            nationality.append(nation.text) //adding the nationality to list


        driver.get(driver.current_url)
        driver.refresh()
        next = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
           EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'paginationPanel'))
        )
        pages = next.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
        for page in pages:
           newlink = page.get_attribute('href')
           newwindow.append(newlink)

         #to get to the next page
         print(newwindow[2])
         driver.get(newwindow[2])
````
`````

Comment: it looks like an api in `json`

Comment: I am really new to web scraping. Like I started learning it 2 days ago. So I have no idea what that means. Can you explain please? I will appreciate it a lot.

Comment: can you provide the code that you've written

Comment: It is not complete, but it gets the data. And puts it in a list. I will manipulate the list later. Right now I am just trying to get all the information. And see if it works or not. But I will post the code. If you find the code funky please let me know ill change it accordingly.

Comment: using `requests` or `selenium`??

Comment: I am using selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `selenium` to click next page instead of getting the `url`. This is a just a simple ,you may need to use a loop and extract data and click next page. I've use variable `browser` instead of `main`.I've written a function and used a for loop to get the data from each page

from selenium import webdriver

```
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException,ElementNotInteractableException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


browser = webdriver.Chrome('/home/cam/Downloads/chromedriver')
url='https://www.interpol.int/en/How-we-work/Notices/View-Red-Notices'
browser.get(url)

def get_data():
    links = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
    years = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("age")
    borns = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("nationalities")
    time.sleep(5)
    try:
        
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="privacy-cookie-banner__privacy-accept"]').click()
    except ElementNotInteractableException:
        pass
    
for i in range(1,9):
    print(i)
    get_data()
    print('//*[@id="paginationPanel"]/div/div/ul/li['+str(i+2)+']/a')
    b=WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="paginationPanel"]/div/div/ul/li['+str(i+2)+']/a')))
    b.click()
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: I tried a similar thing in the past but I was unable to extract information since my window_handles wouldn't update to the new page. Do you think the above code will work? I don't want my driver to stay on the old page since I wouldn't be able to extract new information from the new URL. I hope you understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: lol, can you explain how you were able to update your driver to the new page? I would like to learn that for the future. But overall your code works thanks!!